# Python Requests: .pem -> .crt + key

Tags: openssl, certificate, python-requests

I've been given a .pem file for authentication on an XML POST API.  I would prefer using Python Requests and have found in the documentation that I need to convert the .pem file to a server certification and key.  I have been unable to find exactly what Requests needs (what kind of certification).

I've had to do some openssl conversions on files before, but I'm no expert.  Can anyone explain what kind of certificate and key is needed by Requests and how I can convert a .pem into those files?

For more context into the Requests documentation please see http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

You'll notice a reference to `/path/server.crt` and `/path/key`.

Comment: "server certification and key" does not really tell us much. What do you have, and what do you need? Did you generate a key and submit a CSR? Did you get back a signed X509 cert? What format are things in? PEM or DER/ASN.1?

Comment: I thought I was pretty clear in the question.  I have .pem file.  I need the .crt and key required by Python Request's library.  I don't know what kind of files those are - that is the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a behaviour of requests ([see documentation here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)) that you can take advantage of here without having to generate a `crt` or key files.

Let's say you have the `pem` file here: `/path/to/certificate.pem`, you can then do:

```
r = requests.get('https://example.com', verify='/path/to/cetificate.pem')
```

And it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The path is given as /path/**server**.crt, but the text reads, "You can also specify a local cert to use as **client** side certificate, as a single file (containing the private key and the certificate) or as a tuple of both file’s path..."

Since you have been given a PEM file for *authentication*, it seems that the client is expected to send a CLIENT certificate. You would need a client certificate and client private key.

Look inside that PEM file and you should see the line "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----". Look further, past the "-----END CERTIFICATE----", is there a "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"? If so, you have both the certificate and private key in the same text file, and you can just (according to the doc) use the one file. Or, just cut and paste the RSA key part into a separate text file and name that file "key".