# Accessing S3 using PEM for authentication with Python

Tags: python, ssl-certificate

I was given a PEM file to access a S3 bucket. I can use curl (such as curl -v -k --cert *file_path_in_bucket*, -O https:*ip*/*sourcefilepath* ) to copy files in the bucket -- a good indication that the PEM allows me to access the bucket.

I tried to convert this into a Python requests.get call following [Python Requests: .pem -> .crt + key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705770/python-requests-pem-crt-key) but got the SSLError ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)). It seems to me I need to provide additional info.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the answer is as following:

r= requests.get('https://*ip:port/file_path*', verify=False, cert='*pem_file_path*')

Note, refer the **cert** parameter to pass the pem file.

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

For accessing S3 via Python preferred way is to use BOTO3 library.

Assuming you have configured the SECRET KEY and Credentials its very simple to write..

```
import boto3
s3list = boto3.resource('s3')
print('Displaying list of Buckets I have access to ')
for bucket in s3list.buckets.all():
   print(bucket.name)
```

Comment: I know how to use ACCESS_KEY/ SECRET_KEY to access the bucket. The important element here is that I have to use a PEM file in this situation. Thank you for  willing to help!

Answer (score 0):

This is to upload image using Boto3

```
import boto3
img = open('some.jpg','rb')
s3list.Bucket('mybucket').put_object(Key='some.jpg', Body=img)
```

Answer (score 0):

As they have already suggested to you, boto3 is simple to use.
Here there are my functions for put and get an object to/from an s3 bucket.

```
def putdataons3(localfile, remotefile):
    try:
        bucket = 'yourbucket'
        boto3accesskey = 'your access key'
        boto3secretaccesskey = 'your secret access key'
        boto3client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-central-1', aws_access_key_id=boto3accesskey, aws_secret_access_key=boto3secretaccesskey)
        d = boto3client.put_object(Body=open(localfile, 'rb').read(), Bucket=bucket, Key=remotefile)
        if d['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
            return True
        return False
    except:
        return False

def getdatafroms3(remotefile, localfile, overwrite=True):
    try:
        if overwrite == False:
            if os.path.isfile(localfile):
                return False
        bucket = 'yourbucket'
        boto3accesskey = 'your access key'
        boto3secretaccesskey = 'your secret access key'
        boto3client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-central-1', aws_access_key_id=boto3accesskey, aws_secret_access_key=boto3secretaccesskey)
        d = boto3client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=remotefile)
        if d['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
            f = open(localfile, "wb")
            d = d['Body'].read()
            f.write(d)
            f.close()
            return True
        return False
    except:
        return False
```